# How can I call the data type from the function of a class

Tags: c++

I defined a class as well as member function. And now I would like to call the data type(x.dat) imported from outside.
How could I do that?

It would be something like this:

```
class abs{
private:
...
public:
...
void function(data){     //here i would like to use the external data  x.dat
...
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "calling" a data type? You call functions, not types. What is `x`? What is `dat`?

Comment: Are you talking about loading data from a file x.dat?

Comment: Sorry, not about loading data. the function in public of class abs would use the loading data. I don't know how to use it. where should I load the static data? do I need any pointers in the 'function'? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Keith is correct.

What you want is a static variable that maintains the same data across all objects of that type. You don't necessarily need a function to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class abs
{
private:
public:
    static double data[3];
};
double abs::data[3]={}; //instantiate the variable

int main () {
    abs::data[0]=5.0;
    cout<<abs::data[0]; //outputs 5
}
```

Static variables are associated with the class definition, and not the instantiated objects of that type so as long as the program is active it will be stored in memory as part of the class.

Comment: My data is stored in file 'x.dat', and 'funtion' would use the data as a parameter. I don't where should I load data(double), and how to use in the 'function(double data)'? Thanks

Comment: Okay, let me edit this to better suit what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try my best to be clear. My data, for instance, is of type double[10], I want to load for only once giving some static data in the class 'abs' so that other member functions of the class could use it as a parameter. Please tell me if you don't understand me. you are very kind, thank you!

Comment: `double abs::data[4] = {};` is sufficient to create an array of 0s. This array though is really a global variable, which should be avoided.

Comment: My example is just double[10], what if i have double[1000], not easy for write like this double abs::data[3]={};

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, tremendous thanks to all of you, especially @Mir
I get it running now, although I don't know why does someone give me a negative!?

I would like to make a summary here, for myself, and future readers.

My question is this:

I have a stored data(double[1000]), which is a file of 'x.dat';

And I define a class 'abs' in the header file, as well as its member function 'function';

And 'function' would like to call data as a inputting parameter.
How to do these?

With the help of Mir, it's working now like this, hope it would help someone:

1.abs.h

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <fstream>
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;

        class abs
        {
        private:
        public:
            static double data[1000];
             double function(double xa[]){
                  for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
                     res += xa[i] * 2.0;
                  }
        return res;
             }
        };
```

2.abs.cpp

```
#include "abs.h"

double abs::data[1000]={}; //instantiate the variable
```

3.main.cpp

```
    #include "abs.h"

    int main () {
    abs a = abs();
         for(int i = 0; i < 1000, i++){
           ifstream fs("x.dat")  
           fs   >> abs::data[i];
           cout << abs::data[i]; //outputs all data
         }
    double Value = a.function(data);
    cout<< Value<<endl;
    }
```